# Installation of commercial drivers fails

Tags: drivers, software-installation

Upon trying to install "Software modem" or the "SmartLink modem daemon", a proprietary driver, I get the error

> SystemError: `E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages." Is their anyway to fix this?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and report results. You may also check the "broken" packages in Synaptic package manager and reinstall/remove them.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5835151/ Might I mention that without this driver I can not access the internet.

Comment: Do you have any fallback network connection? Does the wired Ethernet work? If there is any way to connect to the Internet, this will be much easier.

Comment: I cannot connect to ANY wireless networks, I will try wired Ethernet and report back.

Comment: Ethernet works and even after trying your suggestions I got a new error, telling me to refer to jockey.log. Also, it seems if I leave the computer alone a wall of white on black text appears and freezes the mouse and keyboard forcing me to turn it off. Upon trying to do your commands again I get an error about dkpg being locked because it is being accessed by another program, even though no other programs are running.

Comment: @hannahoflane, if you sure that no other programs are using the lock, you can remove it manually: `rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`. Before doing this I recommend run `pkill apt`.